# Не корректно работает ajax скрипт

Tags: ajax

Изучаю аякс, написал небольшой скрипт который записывает данные в бд без перезагрузки, ура. Поправил скрипт так, что бы данные которые улетают в базу, мгновенно отображались на странице. Всё вроде хорошо, но при отражении данных, у меня постоянно копируется форма. Где я ошибся?

Вот как должно быть:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот что получается, форма дублируется, после перезагрузки пропадает:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("document").ready(function(){

            $("#btn").click(function(){

                var title = $("#title").val();
                var description = $("#description").val();
                var texting = $("#texting").val();

                $("#title").val('');
                $("#description").val('');
                $("#texting").val('');

                $.ajax({
                    url: '../Model/AddPost.php',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: {title:title, description:description, texting:texting},
                    success: function(data){
                            $("#textpost").html(data);
                        }
                });

            });

        });
    </script>
    <title>Form</title>
    <style>
        textarea {
            outline: none;
            border: none;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
            resize:none;
        }
        button {
            margin-top: 10px;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
        }
        form {
            margin-top: 10px;
        }
        .post {
            font-size:16px;
        }
        .textpost {
            padding-left:150px;
            padding-right:150px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <center>
    <label for="">Add Post</label>
    <form action="../Model/AddPost.php" method="POST" >
        <textarea id="title" placeholder="Title"  cols="60" rows="2"></textarea><br>
        <textarea id="description" placeholder="Description" name="description" cols="60" rows="2"></textarea><br>
        <textarea id="texting" placeholder="Text" name="texting" cols="60" rows="10"></textarea><br>
        <button id="btn" type="button">Send</button>
    </form>

    <hr>

    <div class="textpost" id="textpost">
        <?php foreach($posts as $post) : ?>
            <div class="post" ><b><?php echo $post['title'] ?></b></div>
            <div class="post" ><i><?php echo $post['description'] ?></i></div>
            <div class="post" ><?php echo $post['texting'] ?></div><br>
        <?php endforeach; ?>    
    </div>
    </center>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы вставляете в `$("#textpost")` всю разметку, которая возвращается php обработчиком.

```
success: function(data) {
  $("#textpost").html($(data).find("#textpost").html());
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, можете объяснить что происходит после $("#textpost")? А то не соображаю уже

Comment: @ШайтанЯкубович Туда надо вставлять только ту порцию html, которая находится внутри такого же элемента в ответе на ajax-запрос. https://api.jquery.com/html/